# Load a 360 panorama image in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, 360-panorama

How do I load a 360 image viewer using forge viewer. One approach I tried was by creating a sphere with image as texture and add it to the overlay scene. Using this, I was able to load a 360 image but I'm getting rendering issues (in some specific views sphere is getting culled).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the skybox sample [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-viewer-skybox-and-camera-animation) and see that fits the bill for you ...